# Tilda terminal on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, ubuntu-17.10

I recently installed Ubuntu 17.10 on my laptop but I cannot use the tilda terminal.
I installed it from the "Ubuntu Software" app but when I try to run it from the default terminal, I get this error:

```
(tilda:7240): Vte-WARNING **: (/build/vte2.91-C4Ziqn/vte2.91-
0.48.4/./src/vtegtk.cc:1736):int 
vte_terminal_match_add_gregex(VteTerminal*, GRegex*, 
GRegexMatchFlags): runtime check failed: 
(g_regex_get_compile_flags(gregex) & G_REGEX_MULTILINE)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Anyone knows have suggestions how I can fix it? I already tried to google but no working solutions.

Thanks a lot,

Isashi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tilda don't have support for the new Wayland interface, but using this command work for me.

```
GDK_BACKEND=x11 tilda
```